# Im using console application in console window i see each line twice why?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int y;
            FileInfo fi;
            string[] newDest_files;
            string[] lines = global::EachFileDirectory.MyResource.video_formats.Split    (new Char[] {'\r','\n'});
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                newDest_files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory,         line); //strFilter );
                for (y = 0; y < newDest_files.Length; y++)
                {
                    fi = new FileInfo(newDest_files[y]);
                    string newFolder = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, fi.Name                 + "_Directory");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(newFolder))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(newFolder);
                    Console.WriteLine("processed: " + line.Length + " files");
                    File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(newFolder, fi.Name));
                }
                if (newDest_files.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line + "No files found in the current directory      of format: ");
             }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n Done! Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();         
    }
}
```

}

The problem is when i have added the line: string[] lines = global::EachFileDirectory.MyResource.video_formats.Split(new Char[] {'\r','\n'});

Since then i see in the console window all the lines double for example:

*.264 No files found in the current directory of format: 
No files found in the current directory of format: 
*.mov No files found in the current directory of format: 
No files found in the current directory of format:

What i need to see in the console window is:

*.264 No files found in the current directory of format: 
*.mov No files found in the current directory of format:

And so on but since i have the line: string[] lines = global::EachFileDirectory.MyResource.video_formats.Split(new Char[] {'\r','\n'});
And also the line in the end of the code: Console.WriteLine(line + "No files found in the current directory of format: ");

I see No files found in the current directory of format:  also in between each line.

How can i fix it ?

On the reference of the project i added a text file wich contain many video formats extentions in this way:

*.264
*.mov
*.avi

and so on.....

The problem is that the text: No files found in the current directory of format: 
Appears near each format and also between two formats and i want ti to be in the console window only near each format !

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting a headache trying to figure out what it is your trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting on `\r` *and* `\n` - which means you're turning input of something like

```
"foo\r\nbar"
```

into:

```
{ "foo", "", "bar" }
```

... so you're then trying to find all the files with an *empty* pattern.

There are various options:

- Create a `StringReader` and call `ReadLine` multiple times instead of using `Split`
- Replace `\r` with the empty string before splitting
- Split on *just* `\n` and then trim each entry
- Specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` after splitting

Answer (score 0):

Add [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) to `Split` method:

```
string[] lines = global::EachFileDirectory.MyResource.video_formats.Split(new Char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```